# How do I join multiple unrelated datasets

Tags: r

In R, I'm trying to join 5 datasets together which do not have any common column.

An example would be to join `mtcars`, `cars` and `iris` datasets together. 
How do I go about?

Using dplyr's

```
full_join(mtcars, cars, iris)
```

returns an error where it tells me by must be a (named) character vector. However I have no common column to use for `'by = '`

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(mtcars, cars, iris)
```

I would like all 3 datasets to be side by side, rows which have no data will be `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to `cbind`, then use `cbind.fill`

```
library(rowr)
cbind.fill(mtcars, cars, iris, fill = NA)
```

The dataset dimensions are not the same, the `fill = NA` will fill those datasets that have less number of rows with NA at the end

---

Or using `tidyverse`, keep the datasets in a `list`, add row names as a column by looping through the `list` and `reduce` to a single dataset joining `by` the 'rowname'

```
library(tidyverse)
list(mtcars, cars, iris) %>%
     map(~ as_tibble(.x) %>%
              rownames_to_column) %>% 
     reduce(full_join, by = 'rowname')
```

Comment: is there any way besides using functions from rowr library? any from tidyverse?

Comment: @wussyx  added an option with `tidyverse`